# BrowserChannelServer IndexSizeError

Tags: gwt

When I'm starting my GWT project in dev mode, this error appears:

> 13:44:59.875 [ERROR] [webapp] Uncaught exception escaped
>
> com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (IndexSizeError)
>   @com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl::apply(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)([JavaScript
>   object(955), JavaScript object(954), JavaScript object(1007)]): Index
>   or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:249)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I can't figure out, where it comes from. Every time it appears, my Image, which i got from a Webservers is not shown. Sometimes it doesn't appear and the image is displayed like it should.
Can u figure out, where this error comes from?

Comment: This is a `JavaScriptException` so it comes from JavaScript in the browser, called from JSNI. Try _breaking on exceptions_ in your browser developer tools to make sense where the exception is coming from. Alternatively, compile in `-style PRETTY` and run in prod mode, hopefully the exception stacktrace in your browser developer tools will provide a hint.

Comment: tried breaking on exceptions, but it did not break >.<

Comment: Note: you have to pause on _all_ exceptions, not only uncaught exceptions.